# Terms Per Page in custom taxonomy Admin

Tags: custom-taxonomy

How can i show all the terms on one page in wp admin area.
I have Custom taxonomy  called brand and i want to get rid of the pagination.
Here is the screenshot http://prntscr.com/f8ghlj
Thanks!

Comment: Looks you have to extend the `WP_List_Table` class. See [here](http://xennis.org/wiki/WordPress_-_Admin_list_table),  [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp_list_table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/) and [prepare_items()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table#Methods) method.

Answer (score 1):

There is the option in screen options menu in right corner.